# JAGS - unable to find appropriate sampler

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models, winbugs, jags, dirichlet

I am trying to develop a hierarchical Dirichlet-multinomial process hidden Markov model in JAGS to estimate multiparty, primary voting intention based on opinion poll results. I also use the primary vote estimate to calculate a two-party preferred vote-share under Australia's preferential voting system.

A dmulti() multinomial distribution has failed with the run-time error message: Unable to find appropriate sampler. I have a work-around that uses a series of binomial distributions and a sum-to-N constraint. Theoretically, this should produce the same result, but it creates space and time inefficienncy in the model.

My question is whether there is something I can do in the hidden, temporal part of the model below to make the multinomial distribution work.

The model (and surrounding R code) follows:

```
data = list(PERIOD = PERIOD,
        HOUSECOUNT = HOUSECOUNT,
        NUMPOLLS = NUMPOLLS,
        PARTIES = PARTIES,
        primaryVotes = primaryVotes,
        pollWeek = df$Week,
        house = as.integer(df$House),
        # manage rounding issues with df$Sample ...
        n = rowSums(primaryVotes),
        preference_flows = preference_flows
    )
print(data)


# ----- JAGS model ...
library(rjags)
model <- "
model {

    #### -- observational model
    for(poll in 1:NUMPOLLS) { # for each poll result - rows
        adjusted_poll[poll, 1:PARTIES] <- walk[pollWeek[poll], 1:PARTIES] +
            houseEffect[house[poll], 1:PARTIES]
        primaryVotes[poll, 1:PARTIES] ~ dmulti(adjusted_poll[poll, 1:PARTIES], n[poll])
    }

    #### -- temporal model (a weekly walk where this week is much like last week)
    #tightness <- 30000 # KLUDGE: value selected by trial and error to look like DLM
    t ~ dunif(1000, 100000) # less kludgy - let the model decide
    tightness <- round(t)
    for(week in 2:PERIOD) { # rows

        # This results in a JAGS runtime error: Unable to find appropriate sampler
        #multinomial[week, 1:PARTIES] ~ dmulti( walk[week-1,  1:PARTIES], tightness)

        # This is the KLUDGE to approximate the above ...
        # Should be the same theoretically ...
        # but results in a larger directed acyclic graph (DAG)
        for(party in 2:PARTIES) {
            multinomial[week, party] ~ dbin(walk[week-1, party], tightness)
        }
        multinomial[week, 1] <- tightness - sum(multinomial[week, 2:PARTIES])

        # The other part of the Dirichlet-Multinomial process
        walk[week, 1:PARTIES] ~ ddirch(multinomial[week, 1:PARTIES])
    }

    ## -- weakly informative priors for first week in the temporal model
    for (party in 1:2) { # for each major party
        alpha[party] ~ dunif(250, 600) # majors between 25% and 60%
    }
    for (party in 3:PARTIES) { # for each minor party
        alpha[party] ~ dunif(10, 250) # minors between 1% and 25%
    }
    walk[1, 1:PARTIES] ~ ddirch(alpha[])

    ## -- estimate a Coalition TPP from the primary votes
    for(week in 1:PERIOD) {
        CoalitionTPP[week] <- sum(walk[week, 1:PARTIES] *
            preference_flows[1:PARTIES])
    }

    #### -- sum-to-zero constraints on house effects
    for (party in 2:PARTIES) { # for each party ...
        # house effects across houses sum to zero
        # NOTE: ALL MUST SUM TO ZERO
        houseEffect[1, party] <- -sum( houseEffect[2:HOUSECOUNT, party] )
    }
    for(house in 1:HOUSECOUNT) { # for each house ...
        # house effects across the parties sum to zero
        houseEffect[house, 1] <- -sum( houseEffect[house, 2:PARTIES] )
    }
    # but note, we do not apply a double constraint to houseEffect[1, 1]
    monitorHouseEffectOneSumParties <- sum(houseEffect[1, 1:PARTIES])
    monitorHouseEffectOneSumHouses <- sum(houseEffect[1:HOUSECOUNT, 1])

    ## -- vague normal priors for house effects - centred on zero
    for (party in 2:PARTIES) { # for each party (cols)
        for(house in 2:HOUSECOUNT) { #  (rows)
            houseEffect[house, party] ~ dnorm(0, pow(0.1, -2))
       }
    }
}
"

jags <- jags.model(textConnection(model),
        data = data,
        n.chains=4,
        n.adapt=n_adapt

)
```

The input data for the model over six months follows.

```
$PERIOD
[1] 27

$HOUSECOUNT
[1] 5

$NUMPOLLS
[1] 37

$PARTIES
[1] 4

$primaryVotes
      Coalition Labor Greens Other
 [1,]       390   375    120   115
 [2,]       407   407    143   143
 [3,]       532   574    154   140
 [4,]       560   518    168   154
 [5,]       350   410    115   125
 [6,]       439   450    139   127
 [7,]       385   385     95   135
 [8,]       375   395    120   110
 [9,]      1465  1483    417   325
[10,]       504   602    154   140
[11,]       532   560    154   154
[12,]       504   602    154   140
[13,]       355   415    120   110
[14,]       412   483    141   141
[15,]      1345  1450    392   312
[16,]       375   405    100   120
[17,]       448   448    142   142
[18,]       588   504    168   140
[19,]       390   380    115   115
[20,]       441   453    139   128
[21,]       380   400    110   110
[22,]       471   425    126   126
[23,]       957   979    278   205
[24,]       405   360    125   110
[25,]       546   532    182   126
[26,]       471   413    126   138
[27,]       385   380    120   115
[28,]      1008   995    301   228
[29,]       400   375    115   110
[30,]       457   410    141   164
[31,]       690   656    185   151
[32,]       603   491    182   126
[33,]       415   355    125   105
[34,]       464   429    139   128
[35,]      1307  1218    385   273
[36,]       410   370    130    90
[37,]       479   433    152   105

$pollWeek
 [1]  1  1  2  2  3  3  7  9  9 10 10 11 11 11 11 13 13 14 15 15 17 17 18 19 20
[26] 20 21 22 23 23 25 25 25 25 25 27 27

$house
 [1] 3 4 1 2 3 4 3 3 5 1 2 1 3 4 5 3 4 2 3 4 3 4 5 3 2 4 3 5 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 3 4

$n
 [1] 1000 1100 1400 1400 1000 1155 1000 1000 3690 1400 1400 1400 1000 1177 3499
[16] 1000 1180 1400 1000 1161 1000 1148 2419 1000 1386 1148 1000 2532 1000 1172
[31] 1682 1402 1000 1160 3183 1000 1169

$preference_flows
[1] 1.0000 0.0000 0.1697 0.5330
```

A comparison of the output (compared with other models I have) follows. The red line in the next chart was generated from the above.

[image]